# Visual studio Lightswitch - Version management

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, version-control, version, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a business LS web application which I update from time to time.
I do the update by simply using the deploy wizard and everything is working great.
My problem is handling all my users that opened my system in their IE and left it open through my deploy process.

Since they have the old web application is opened on their browsers, and I have deployed the new version to the server, I can see errors occuring in certain situations.
Is there a way to make sure all users with the application opened will be forced to refresh the web application page? Maybe remotely disconnect all currently connected users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in way of doing this. You will need to write a custom solution. Someone in the MSDN Forums has [written a class](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/9a24ae20-c7c4-42a7-a3b5-e492c4a644e9/) to do this for OOB apps.

You should be able to reuse the timer part of that class. I'm not sure if the `UpdateAvailable` method will work for Web-based applications or not. You'll have to experiment with that.

Alternatively, you can create a custom notification system. Insert a message to your users into a table in your database from the administrator account. Have a timer on the user account check the table every so often. If it finds a new message, display a notification to the user.

Then you can use either an HTTP Response Header or an ASP method to log the users out as described in [this Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315584).